# ¿Como leer correos de una cuenta con varios buzones en C#?

Tags: c#, .net, email

Tengo un programita que es capaz de leer los correos de  mi cuenta principal, pero necesito que lea los correos de otro buzón que no es mi buzón principal, si no de uno que tengo provilegios, pero no es mi buzón principal. Hasta ahora solo he conseguido eso, que lea los de mi buzón principal, os adjunto el código de la conexión y de como accede a la carpeta que quiero que lea, a ver si podeis ayudarme. ¡Gracias!

```
Log.Message("Intentando conectar con el servidor de Exchange");

ServiceInstance.Credentials = new WebCredentials(User, Password);
ServiceInstance.AutodiscoverUrl(User, RedirectionCallback);

FolderView view = new FolderView(100);
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
view.PropertySet.Add(FolderSchema.DisplayName);
view.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;
FindFoldersResults re = ServiceInstance.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Root, view);
folder = ServiceInstance.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Root, view).Where(x => x.DisplayName == FolderName).First();
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Particularmente que problema tenes cuando vas a la otra casilla?

Comment: Cuando leo de un correo normal no hay ningún problema, el problema es que tengo que leer los correos de un buzón donde un usuario tiene permisos, pero no es su buzón principal, y no se cambiar del buzón principal a ese que tiene permisos.